# Problems with lauching my Ubuntu on dual boot

Tags: operating-system, operator-overloading

When I try to run my ubuntu on dusl boot I get message:
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, .../.. files, .../... blocks.
How can I repare it or get to my ubuntu?
I have tried to reset it few times and also find on internet some solutions to write something on terminal but in fact I cant get to terminal because I cant launch it. So how can I repare it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot into your BIOS. This is on every brand of computer diffrent but most of the time you need to spam press F12, F10, F2.

Once you are booted in Bios you can try to change the default boot drive by the "boot" option.

Comment: And is there a possibility that it will run after some time?